# Pattern matching a combination Maybe and Either

Tags: haskell

How to match pattern

```
Maybe (Either (Int, String) String)
```

I need to write function with such kind of input and how it is possible to parse such input?

Comment: why minus? explain please

Comment: I have to guess here but I think there is a good chance because you posted similar questions one right after another. It would probably go over better if you had shown what you had tried and how it failed. It is rare for anything to be down voted if the effort is apparent. When you converse in person it is possible to pick up on how much effort is being applied by various non-verbal methods, but on the internet we do not have this so to compensate it can, but not always, be help to be a little more verbose, but only when it allows for additional insite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Maybe a` type has the patterns `Just a` and `Nothing`. The `Either a b` type has the patterns `Left a` and `Right b`. So a value of type `Maybe (Either (Int, String) String)` can match the following patterns:

- `Nothing`
- `Just (Left (x,y))` where `x` is an `Int` and `y` is a `String`
- `Just (Right z)` where `z` is a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

```
f :: Maybe (Either (Int, String) String) -> <SOMETHING>
f x = case x of
    Just (Left (i, s)) -> <...>
    Just (Right s) -> <...>
    Nothing -> <...>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
matchme Nothing = "Nothing"
matchme (Just (Left (x,y)) = "Left " ++ show x ++ " " + y
matchme (Just (Right z)) = "Right " ++ z
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also use the `maybe` and `either` functions, like so:

```
matchit = maybe nothing (left `either` right)
  where
      nothing = {- value for the nothing case -}
      left (x,y) = {- code for the (Just (Left (x,y)) case -}
      right z = {- code for the (Just (Right z)) case -}
```